# web3.min.js is missing in ./node_modules/web3/dist

Tags: web3js, blockchain, javascript

I am following the below tutorial to create implement blockchain using web3.

https://medium.com/coinmonks/interacting-with-ethereum-smart-contracts-through-web3-js-e0efad17977

When I am using **npm install ethereum/web3.js --save** web3/dist is not getting created at all and is unable to find **./node_modules/web3/dist/web3.min.js**.

On using **npm install web3 --save** web3/dist is getting created but **web3.min.js** is missing.

As per the tutorial and all other tutorials, need this in my script.

I need help!!!

Comment: use this command it will work
npm install web3@0.20.6 --save

Answer (score 1):

This solved the issue:

**npm install ethereum/web3.js#develop --save --verbose**

Answer (score 0):

try using this link. It is the cdn

`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ethereum/web3.js@0.18.2/dist/web3.min.js"></script>`

Comment: `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/web3@latest/dist/web3.min.js` OR `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/web3@latest/dist/web3.min.js` worked for me